# Two Points in a 2d Shape

Tags: geometry

Can you come up with a single continuous 2d shape and 2 points (A and B), such that no ray from Point A, reflecting infinitely off of the walls, will hit Point B? Two walls cannot be infinitely close to each other, nor can A and B be the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, the following shape seems to work (depending on definitions):

[image]

Point $A$ is the center of two inner circular arcs of radius $r$ and the center of two outer circular arcs of radius $r+ \delta r$. Any ray from $A$ hitting an inner circular arc would bounce back, hit $A$, hit the other inner circular arc and bounce back, hit $A$, and so on indefinitely. Similarly for a ray hitting an outer circular arc. Point $B$ would never be hit.

This assumes, of course, that the normal to the endpoint of a circular arc is no different from the normal to any other point on that circular arc.

Comment: A crafty and correct solution. Can you think of an answer that does not involve circles?

Comment: Thanks! Regarding shapes not involving circles, it seems tougher. Do you know that such a shape exists?

Comment: No--I do not. I am on the hunt. What is most of interest to me at the moment is the development of rules for which areas a ray will not touch when infinitely reflecting off walls.

Comment: I recently watched a video on the illumination problem, which turns out to be the same problem as the one I introduced here. A rectilinear response (and a beautiful one at that) is offered. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhj5er1k6GQ&t=290s